# How to read youtube comments using Selenium?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, youtube

I'm trying to read youtube video comments using the following code:

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcbBNpYkuW4");

WebElement element = driver.findElementByCssSelector("#watch-discussion");
System.out.println(element.getText()); // this prints: loading..

// scrolll down so that comments start to load
driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");

Thread.sleep(10000);

element = driver.findElementByCssSelector("#watch-discussion");
System.out.println(element.getText());
```

Last statement prints an empty string. Why?

Comment: Inside the `<div> watch-discussion` there is an `iframe`, you'll need to `switchTo()` that frame before `webdriver` can see the contents of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be little tricky because all the comments are written in a separate iframe tag inside watch discussion. You will have to switch on that iframe first using driver.switchTo().frame("put ID or Name here"); but the iframe id is random value. After switch to that iframe you can find the comments all comments in a div that have class name 'Ct' so you can get those using XPATH. see the below working code

```
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcbBNpYkuW4");

WebElement element = driver.findElementByCssSelector("#watch-discussion");
System.out.println(element.getText()); // this prints: loading..

// scrolll down so that comments start to load
driver.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,500)", "");

Thread.sleep(20000);

List<WebElement> iframes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//iframe"));

for(WebElement e : iframes) {       
    if(e.getAttribute("id") != null && e.getAttribute("id").startsWith("I0_")) {
    // switch to iframe which contains comments
    driver.switchTo().frame(e);
    break;
    }
}

// fetch all comments
List<WebElement> comments = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='Ct']"));
for(WebElement e : comments) {      
    System.out.println(e.getText());
}
```

Comment: does your code returns all possible comments or it is restricted by the maximun number of comments that YouTube API can return?

Comment: No, This code is just to reach at youtube comments section. you tube does not provide all comments in first load if number of comments are more. You will required changes to get all, like click on "show more" button if present at the end of the page.

Comment: I have some problem to run you script(I haven't run java via cmd before). If you have run your script in cmd can you suggest me how to run it? Since now, I have `javac -classpath "C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-java-2.42.2.jar;C:\selenium-2.42.2\selenium-firefox-driver-2.42.2.jar" comments.java
java comments` but an exception error about firefox-driver is returned. Thanks!

Comment: are you able to run your program using eclipse ?

Comment: I have never used eclipse before. I will give a try but I mostly keep interested in running it in cmd. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java) API which is very easy/reliable instead of relying on the X-path of the elements. Also you cannot rely on the Xpath for dynamic pages/content.